# Does LLVM support or ever support PathProfiling well?

Tags: profiling, llvm

Our project needs a tool to gather path profiling information of a program, so I turn to LLVM for help.
However, it seems the function we need is removed since version 3.4. I try the version 3.3 instead, and I find that edge profiling, optimal edge profiling works well. When it comes to path profiling, it simply doesn't work.
And I can't find libprofile_rt.so in version 3.3 build, I download one from http://rpmfind.net/ instead.

The command I use:

opt -insert-path-profiling -o example.pp.bc example.bc

lli -load WHERE_YOUR_LIBPROFILE_RE_SO_LIES/libprofile_rt.so example.pp.bc

#it produces llvmprof.out successfully

llvm-prof example.pp.bc

#then following error occurs : llvm-prof: Unknown packet type #5!

So, my question is :

1.Is there a new version that support PathProfiling again?

2.Any historical version of LLVM support PathProfiling well? If any, please tell me the version number ...

I've checked some old dev mails. The answer to my questions seems to be "NO". But the newest mails were written 2 years ago. Since LLVM is pretty hot these years and a long time passed, I want to make sure the questions above again and get the up-to-date answer.

I hope I make the problem I met clear. Your comments are very welcome.
Thanks